# Integrating Autodesk Plant 3D with Remote SQL Databases

Tags: autocad, autodesk

Can Autodesk Plant 3D connect to an external database, such as one hosted on Digital Ocean? I'd like to sync Plant 3D with changes made in a SQL database so that updates there are automatically reflected in Plant 3D.

While I'm aware that connecting to an MS SQL server is doable, it seems more tailored to local setups. I'm exploring options beyond that, possibly including remote databases.